# TypeError while creating a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have written the following python code using the pandas package.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series

csv = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df_csv = pd.DataFrame(csv)

PassengerId = np.array(df_csv['PassengerId'])
Age = np.array(df_csv['Age'])
Pclass = np.array(df_csv['Pclass'])
Sex = np.array(df_csv['Sex'])

i = 0
while i < 891:
    if Sex[i] == 'male':
        Sex[i] = 0
        i = i + 1
    else:
        Sex[i] = 1
        i = i + 1
Sex = np.array(Sex)
new_df = pd.DataFrame[
    'PassengerId': Series(PassengerId),
    'Age': Series(Age),
    'Pclass': Series(Pclass),
    'Sex': Series(Sex)
]

print(new_df)
```

I am trying to create a data frame by reading a csv file, storing a few columns as numpy array then replacing value of one array. when i merge those arrays again as a data frame, i get the following error

```
D:\Projects\Titanic>python python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 27, in <module>
    'Sex': Sex
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: this is invalid: `new_df = pd.DataFrame[
    'PassengerId': Series(PassengerId),
    'Age': Series(Age),
    'Pclass': Series(Pclass),
    'Sex': Series(Sex)
]` it should be round parenthese `()` additionally you should pass a dict `new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PassengerId': Series(PassengerId),
    'Age': Series(Age),
    'Pclass': Series(Pclass),
    'Sex': Series(Sex)
})`

Comment: Thank You! It worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame[
  'PassengerId': Series(PassengerId),
  'Age': Series(Age),
  'Pclass': Series(Pclass),
  'Sex': Series(Sex)
]
```

with

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
  'PassengerId': Series(PassengerId),
  'Age': Series(Age),
  'Pclass': Series(Pclass),
  'Sex': Series(Sex)
})
```